# Unable to select only mesh on Rigged Object

Tags: mesh, rigging, selection-tools, layers

I'm new to blender.   I'm working with a rigged model that I've downloaded from a sharing site.  I'm trying to move the model from one layer to another for compositing purposes.  When I attempt to select the rigged character, however, and then move it using the "M" key, only the underlying rig gets moved to the new layer.  The mesh is left behind.

When I attempt to select the mesh in object mode, however, I cannot.   If I go in to edit mode, however, the layers are no longer available.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Check the Outliner window to see if the object has been made selectable or not. For moving the whole rig and associated meshes, if you can create a group after selecting all of the parts and rig, then you can change the Outliner to show Groups and then select the whole group and move it to the new layer.

Comment: As Homer Simpson would say:  Doh!

The "selectable" arrow was unchecked.   Thanks!

Comment: @BradHoehne Could you please accept and upvote the answer if it was helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of scenarios that this may happen:

- Make sure the mesh and armature are parented, to do this, select the mesh first then <kbd>shift</kbd> and select the armature then hit<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> then Automatic weighting
- The object you are trying to select is not selectable, do fix this you need to check the selectable mouse pointer icon beside the object in the object outliner view as shown:

[image]